# Can we make a nav color dynamic with some button to click and add js on it?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am new at the world of programming I make a small nav bar like this and I want to add a button when it click it should change the color.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4jfx.png)

I made the nav bar and brought all icons but now I don't know hot to add a functionality on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are few way to change color with pseudo-classes with selectors.

```css
<selector>:hover {
/* 
when the mouse move over to the link then you can do something change in here.
*/
}

<selector>:focus {
/* 
which means that when the mouse hold the mouse left click keep press do something change in here.
*/
}

<selector>:visited {
/* 
this might you want effect when user visited the link css to do. 
*/
}
```

There has more pseudo-classes can do, please check the link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited